# Difference-in-Difference with two control groups and one treatment group over the same period of time using RStudio

Tags: r, categorical-encoding, treatment-effect

So I'm trying to run a regression for one of my economics classes with one treatment group and two control groups over a period of time. I'm currently trying to create a dummy (binary) variable to account for the fixed effects, but the dependent variable that I'm trying to calculate is also a dummy (binary variable). When trying to create the dummy variable one of my treatment groups is unaccounted for due to perfect multicollinearity. Here's my code for trying to create the dummy variable if it helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am by no means an expert when using R, so if you need some further clarification feel free to ask.

Edit: `DH` is the binary variable stating whether or not the country received the treatment. I'm pretty sure that is where the error is occurring because the two control groups both have values of 0.

```
dummyvar = lm(GDP ~ DH + factor(Year) + factor(Country), data = datar)
summary(dummyvar)
```

Comment: Welcome. It appears the fixed effects absorb your treatment variable. It could just be a coding issue. When does treatment start? Your policy variable should ‘switch on’ for treated units *and* only in the periods when treatment is actually in effect. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for replying. I've done some more research pertaining to my question, and I've concluded that the model above cannot be used due to the fact that my variable of interest is a binary variable. My question now is how one account for time fixed effects and state fixed effects does when the variable of interest is time-invariant?

Comment: The effect occurs in 2004 which is treated as a "breakpoint" year and is not included in the regression.  My regression I'm trying to run is of the form: realGDP~treatment. Basically I'm trying to determine the effect of the treatment on GDP.

Comment: Please help me understand something. I see you indicated that you're working with a limited **dependent** variable, but the left-hand side of your equation is annual GDP. Are you referring to the dichotomous treatment variable or the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently trying to create a dummy (binary) variable to account for the fixed effects, but the dependent variable that I'm trying to calculate is also a dummy (binary variable).

I am not sure whether you're referring to the policy variable or the country fixed effects, or both. The country "dummies" (plural) represent *country* fixed effects, while the year "dummies" (plural) represent *year* fixed effects. The treatment "dummy" (singular) should be one variable representing when treatment 'turns on' (i.e., switches from 0 to 1) in treated countries. In other words, `HR` equals 1 for treated countries *and* only in their post-treatment years, 0 otherwise. The equation you're considering allows for almost any treatment pattern. For example, the onset of treatment is allowed to start at different times in different countries; treatment is even allowed to reverse, meaning that the treatment variable may 'turn off' (i.e., switch from 1 back to 0) within countries after a brief exposure period. I would pay close attention to the treatment variation *within countries* over time.

> When trying to create the dummy variable one of my treatment groups is unaccounted for due to perfect multicollinearity.

You didn't really show us "how" you coded the policy variable. Instead, all you've showed us is the equation you estimated in R. Let's first consider what you're estimating:

$$
\text{GDP}_{it} = \delta\text{DH}_{it} + \alpha_i + \lambda_t + u_{it},
$$

where you observe $\text{GDP}$ in country $i$ in year $t$. The parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\lambda_t$ denote fixed effects for countries and years, respectively. The policy variable $\text{DH}_{it}$ is the primary variable of interest. It should equal 1 in only those country-year combinations where the policy is in effect, 0 otherwise.

Now you indicated that software is dropping $\text{DH}_{it}$, which shouldn't be the case assuming you observe countries before *and* after the policy and you acquired control group. I suspect the country fixed effects fully absorb your treatment variable, which suggests it's a time-invariant regressor. The country fixed effects already account for time-constant factors, which include a country's membership to the treatment group. Again, your treatment variable should switch from 0 to 1 in only those country-year pairs where the treatment in effect, 0 otherwise.

On the other hand, assuming the policy goes into effect at the same time in all countries, then it's also possible that your treatment variable is being absorbed by the time fixed effects. This would happen in settings where all countries experience the same shock/exposure and in precisely the same year. I find this scenario less plausible, as you already indicated that you have a subset of countries never exposed to treatment. To avoid this issue, ensure $\text{DH}_{it}$ is equal to unity in treated countries *and* in their post-treatment periods, 0 otherwise. Note how "0 otherwise" means $\text{DH}_{it}$ is equal to 0 in the years before the policy in *treated countries*, and 0 **in all years** in *control countries*.